# How to free an Object when its down to 1 reference, not zero

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Is there a way to free an Object when its referenced only once (in my Ressources-Dictionary)?

What I like to do:

```
// Objects of Type Data have no public constructor. Ressources is the only way to get them.
Ressources.GetOrCreate ("asdf"); // Creates one reference, stores it in a private Dictionary.

Data x = Ressources.GetOrCreate ("asdf"); // 2 references

Data y = x;   // 3 references
y = null;     // 2 references
x = null;     // 1 references. Time for Ressources to remove it from its Dictionary
```

Is there a way to do that (preferebly without needing to hack the whole GarbageCollection System)?

Comment: You may wnat to look into WeakReferences. The question is not very clear otherwise.

Comment: You should look at `WeakReference`. Other than that, there is no way since .NET doesn't use a reference count for dealing with GC.